# Search a mssql db through android

Tags: php, android, sql-server, database, json

I have a android application, that in theory, would use php as a proxy and search a mssql db for a set of variables(i.e. start date, end date, and username). I know how I would do it in theory. android http post->php query ->mssql response->php encode-> android list view.

3 things I was wondering if you could help me figure out.

1)how to search two tables for the information

2)I'm accessing a HUGE db any tips or advice on handling sure a large db through android.

3)and lastly some good tuts on this sort of thing

Comment: 1. Completely dependent on the structure of your data. Post some table schemas and we can provide more help.  
2. Not a problem, since the database is on your server, not the phone.   
3. Not sure what else to say

Comment: Although you have HUGE database, with efficient indexing and suitable query, it should not have problems on fetching data effectively.

Comment: Haven't you got any correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using PHP why are you thinking to search values in android phone? PHP can do your searching part. You could put necessary conditions for extracting data. Then store in some variable of array and echo it using `echo json_encode($variable);`

Get the values in your android using `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` now you have the data you wanted and which will consume less bandwidth of your device.

Answer (score 0):

1)how to search two tables for the information

I think the logic to access db is in PHP, so you just make a proper gateway is fine.

2)I'm accessing a HUGE db any tips or advice on handling sure a large db through android.

Even you are dealing with huge db, but you could only need to display few of it on your android phone at a time, suppose it's paging, I recommend you to make a Buffer, to read as many as pages you can do, and then fetch pages from buffer (not network), if the page index is beyond Buffer, then update buffer by networking.

Hope it helps.